# Lists subitems in collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a collection gotten with eager loading in Laravel 5.1. I know there's a method which helps me to get a list of specific columns. But I need to get the last relationship in my super collection.

The code below helps me to get my office's routes, the routes customers and customer's credits.

```
$offices = Office::with( 'routes.customers.creditos' )->where( 'user_id', '=', $user->id )->get();
```

Returning the following (array format):

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:10 [
    "id" => 10
    ...
    "routes" => array:2 [
      0 => array:10 [
        "id" => 1
        ...
        "customers" => array:2 [
          0 => array:21 [
            "id" => 1
            ...
            "creditos" => array:1 [
               "id" => 1
               ...
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

I need return just the credits:

```
$creditos = $offices->lists( 'routes.customers.creditos' )->all();
```

It doesn't work, seems lists() method just get the columns in first level...

Comment: Where does the user_id column live?

Comment: Looking at your query suggests that in offices, but it wouldn't make much sense

Comment: user_id column lives in office model. The idea is get an specific nested collection after eager loading. Each office in offices has routes, each route has customers, each customer has credits.... I just want return the credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) 2 options:

- you fetch all offices data like you did and then extract credits only - if you only need credits in your action you'll fetch a lot of unnecessary data and run a few unnecessary queries
- fetch only credits for given office - this will give a bit more complex query

**Option 1:**

```
$offices = Office::with( 'routes.customers.creditos' )->where( 'user_id', '=', $user->id )->get();
$creditos = array();
$offices->routes->map(function($route) use ($creditos) {
  $route->customers->map(function($customer) use ($creditos) {
    $creditos = array_merge($creditos, $customer->creditos->all());
  });
});
```

**Option 2:**

```
 $creditos = Credit::join('customers', 'creditos.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
  ->join('routes', 'customers.route_id', '=', 'routes.id')
  ->join('offices', 'routes.office_id', '=', 'offices.id')
  ->where('offices.user_id', '=', $user_id)
  ->get();
```

Comment: I thought there was an easier way to do that... But I see loops are the solution. Thank you very much.